Unity: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build
When building my project I get the following error:

An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
Asset: 'Assets/Assets/Tilesets/006/SavePoint-animation-sprite.png'
Asset name: SavePoint-animation-sprite
(You are probably referencing internal Unity data in your build.)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

These are the properties of the png in question:

The asset is used in a prefab that looks like this:

(I collapsed the box collider so you could see the entire inspector).
The MapEvent script you see it's a simple script that contains the following code:
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class MapEvent: MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Properties

    [Inject]
    private GameEventsSystem gameEventsSystem;

    public enum TriggerType
    {
        OnStep = 0,
        OnCollision,
        OnCollisionFacing,
        OnInteract
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private EventData eventData;
    [SerializeField]
    private TriggerType trigger = TriggerType.OnStep;

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (!col.CompareTag("Player"))
            return;

        switch (trigger)
        {
            case TriggerType.OnCollision:
                PlayEvent();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        if (trigger != TriggerType.OnInteract)
            return;
    
        PlayEvent();
    }

    private void PlayEvent()
    {
        eventData.gameObject = gameObject;
        gameEventsSystem.CallEvent(eventData);
    }

    #endregion Methods
}

And EventData is a Scriptable Object that contains this code:
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif


[CreateAssetMenu]
public class EventData : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameEventsSystem.EventType eventType = GameEventsSystem.EventType.NoEvent;

    [ShowIf("eventType", GameEventsSystem.EventType.OpenDialogue)]
    public Dialogue dialogue;
    
    [ShowIf("eventType", GameEventsSystem.EventType.OpenScene)]
    [ValueDropdown("ListOfScenes")]
    public string scene;
    [ShowIf("eventType", GameEventsSystem.EventType.OpenScene)]
    public Vector3 playerPosition;
    
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject gameObject;

    private string[] ListOfScenes
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var scenes = new string[EditorBuildSettings.scenes.Length];
            
            for (var i = 0; i < EditorBuildSettings.scenes.Length; i++)
                scenes[i] = EditorBuildSettings.scenes[i].path;

            return scenes;
#else
            return new[] { scene };
#endif
        }
    }

    public object[] GetParams()
    {
        return eventType switch
        {
            GameEventsSystem.EventType.OpenDialogue => new object[] {dialogue},
            GameEventsSystem.EventType.OpenScene => new object[] {scene, playerPosition},
            GameEventsSystem.EventType.GrabPot => new object[] {gameObject},
            _ => new object[] { }
        };
    }
}

As you can see, I never use HideFlags.DontSave.
I don't know if I gave you all the context needed to help but if anything else is needed I will provide it.

can you scroll down on the texture inspector? do you have any asset post-processors there?

Hey @derHugo sorry for late reply, the error disappeared after shutting down unity and PC and turning everything back on....
